# Automate a Listbox value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Hello I'm trying to automate a value into a website that has two list boxes in it.
For the first List box this code works, However It doesn't work for the second list box. I can't just copy and paste this code below it for the second one even if I change the variable "a". Any help is appreciated!

```
For a = 1 To cats.Options.Length
If cats.Options(a).Text = "Option One" Then
cats.selectedindex = a
Exit For
End If
Next a
```

Comment: The list boxes probably have different names. If you right click on each box and inspect elements, you can view the HTML and see what each box is referred to and adjust as needed.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work."  Show your attempted code.

Comment: is not just the variable "a". Read the code, look at how "cats" was assigned, once you understand it, you need to assign the next list so you can loop through it just like the one that is working. If you cant still get it to work, edit the post with more code or provide the website, or both.

Comment: You most certainly don't want to copy-pasta anything anyway. Show us your code, this is just a snippet taken out of context. What's not working? How?

Comment: `For a = 0 To cats.Options.Length-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with multiple lists then you should come up with a re-useable block of code which you can call for any list+value.

Something like:

```
Function SetByTextValue(lst as object, v as string) As Boolean
    Dim a as long
    For a = 0 To lst.Options.Length - 1
        If lst.Options(a).Text = v Then
            lst.selectedindex = a
            SetByTextValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

Then in your main code you can do something like:

```
If Not SetByTextValue(cats, "Option One") Then
   'not found
Else
   '...proceed with next list
End If
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!